# How to filter out only the first element not matching a predicate in a Java sequential Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, filtering, java-stream

I'm stuck on an edge case in java stream manipulations...

I want to code the following behavior: "From an arbitrary basket of fruits, collect the 20 smallest, except the smallest pear, because we don't want that."

Added bonus: the baskets to come might not have any pear at all.

Examples :

- From [Pear 5, Apple 1, Apple 2, Apple 10, Pear 3, Pear 7], we want [Apple 1, Apple 2, Pear 5, Pear 7, Apple 10].
- From [Apple 4, Apple 7, Pear 8, Pear 2, Pear 3], we want [Pear 3, Apple 4, Apple 7, Pear 8].

So far, I'm at this step:

```
output = basket.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Fruit::getSize))
    //.filter(???)
    .limit(20)
    .collect(fruitCollector);
```

This seems like a case of **stateful** lambda filter, and I don't know how to do that.

I can't use a local `firstPear` boolean and set it to `true` after filtering the first pear, since all local variables in a lambda must be final.

Worst case scenario I can split the basket in two, pears and non-pears, sort the pears, and sublist them appropriately if there is any. This seems very inefficient and ugly. **Is there a better way?**

---

### [Edit] Answer comparison

There was much variety in the answers posted here, and most of them are valid. In order to give back to the community, I put together a [small testing harness](https://github.com/RabidFX/java-streams-stateful-filtering) to compare the performance of these algorithms.

This comparison was not as extensive as I wanted - It's been 3 weeks already. It **only covers usage for sequential processing of simple items**. Feel free to give the testing harness a go, and add more tests, more benchmarks, or your own implementation.

My analysis:

```
Algorithm                | Author   | Perf | Comments
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Indexed removal          | Holger   | Best | Best overall, somewhat obscure
Stateful predicate       | pedromss | Best | Do not use for parallel processing
Straightforward approach | Misha    | Best | Better when few elements match
Custom collector         | Eugene   | Good | Better when all or no element match
Comaprator hack w/ dummy | yegodm   | Good | -
Comparator hack          | xenteros | *    | Perf sensitive to output size, fails on edge cases.
```

I acecpted pedromss' answer, as it's the one we implemented in the project, due to both its good performance, and "black-box" capabilities (the state-managing code is in an external class, and contributors can focus on the business logic).

**Note that the accepted answer might not be the best for you: review the others, or check [my testing project](https://github.com/RabidFX/java-streams-stateful-filtering) to see for yourself.**

Comment: Is the use of Streams a requirement?

Comment: @VGR It's merely recommended to maintain code homogeneity, but I'll accept any elegant solution... See my "worst case scenario" for what I find inelegant ;)

Comment: Filter predicates have to be stateless, so I doubt this can be done with a single Stream.  I think this is a case where a loop is the better approach.

Comment: @SilverQuettier I have found a hack and attached below - I hope you could use it in your case!

Comment: Stream are ment to query a group of elements which all the element behave the same but they may have different values. Here you are trying to query a group of elements from the same type + `k` other elements that are different from all of the others (`k` in this case equal to `1`) and you, in this example, want to react to them in different way. Stream can't do that.. at list not in one nice pipeline. **There must be a well defined rule on what exactly is the type of problem streams are ment to solve.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a stateful predicate:

```
class StatefulPredicate<T> implements Predicate<T> {

    private boolean alreadyFiltered;
    private Predicate<T> pred;

    public StatefulPredicate(Predicate<T> pred) {
        this.pred = pred;
        this.alreadyFiltered = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(T t) {
        if(alreadyFiltered) {
            return true;
        }

        boolean result = pred.test(t);
        alreadyFiltered = !result;
        return result;
    }
}

    Stream.of(1, -1, 3, -4, -5, 6)
        .filter(new StatefulPredicate<>(i -> i > 0))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints: `1, 3, -4, -5, 6`

If concurrency is an issue you can use an atomic boolean.

If you wish to skip more than 1 element, add that parameter to your constructor and build your logic inside `StatefulPredicate`

This predicate filters the first negative element and then lets every other element pass, regardless. In your case you should test for `instanceof Pear`

## Edit

Since people showed concerns about filter being stateless, from the documentation:

> Intermediate operations are further divided into stateless and stateful operations. Stateless operations, such as filter and map, retain **no state from previously seen element when processing a new element** -- each element can be processed independently of operations on other elements. Stateful operations, such as distinct and sorted, may incorporate state from previously seen elements when processing new elements.

That predicate doesn't retain information about previously seen elements. It retains information about previous results.

Also it can be made thread safe to avoid concurrency issues.

Comment: “You can use a stateful predicate” No, you can’t.  The [documentation of Stream.filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) is very clear:  the Predicate must be “a non-interfering, stateless predicate.”

Comment: @VGR first of that only applies if you allow the stream to run concurrently. Secondly I mention that if concurrency is an issue he should make the predicate thread safe. So... yea... Plus if you read the docs you linked, filter is "an intermediate operation that retains no information about previsouly seen elements". The predicate I presented doesn't retain information about previous elements, it retains information about previous results.

Comment: You're both right: [official doc about statelessness in predicates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness). The predicates are expected to be sateless. However, this rule is meant to avoid contention or parallelism issues, and you warned about this in your solution, @pedromss . Bending the rules for an edge case like this might be acceptable. I'll run some tests :)

Comment: @pedromss The recommendation against stateful predicates definitely applies to your solution. It is subject to all the caveats described in the documentation. Saying it only retains information about result doesn't help: those results depend on the elements, and the state of the filter reflects which elements have been seen.

Comment: I have tested your solution amongst others. The results are above, feel free to challenge them if I made a mistake in the implementation. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered a straightforward approach?  Find the smallest pear, filter it out (if it exists) and collect 20 smallest:

```
Optional<Fruit> smallestPear = basket.stream()
        .filter(Fruit::isPear)  // or whatever it takes to test if it's a pear
        .min(Fruit::getSize);

Stream<Fruit> withoutSmallestPear = smallestPear
        .map(p -> basket.stream().filter(f -> f != p))
        .orElseGet(basket::stream);

List<Fruit> result = withoutSmallestPear
        .sorted(comparing(Fruit::getSize))
        .limit(20)
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Yes, it's close to the "worst case scenario" I evoked in the question. This raises concerns about code performance and stability, but it'll work. I'll have a look, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Do you actually have a performance problem (and a metric to measure against)?  You will probably find that the performance cost will be dominated by the sorting and doing a simple scan to find the smallest pear makes little difference.  Besides, conventional wisdom is to code for clarity and only optimize for performance once you have a reason to.  I find the approach I propose to be the easiest to be confident about. I certainly find it preferable to stateful predicates or custom collectors.  But clarity is in the eye of the beholder, so you decide.

Comment: This is straight-forward and streaming over `basket` twice may be irrelevant to the performance, but there is [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46040870/2711488) that works without and still is straight-forward. Just collect into a mutable list of at most 21 elements and remove either, the first `Pear`, if there is one, or the 21st element, if there is one.

Comment: I have tested your solution amongst others. The results are above, feel free to challenge them if I made a mistake in the implementation. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell this has *custom* written all over it, so I did try a custom collector here:

```
private static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> exceptCollector(Predicate<T> predicate, int size, Comparator<T> comparator) {

    class Acc {

        private TreeSet<T> matches = new TreeSet<>(comparator);

        private TreeSet<T> doesNot = new TreeSet<>(comparator);

        void accumulate(T t) {
            if (predicate.test(t)) {
                matches.add(t);
            } else {
                doesNot.add(t);
            }
        }

        Acc combine(Acc other) {

            matches.addAll(other.matches);
            doesNot.addAll(other.doesNot);

            return this;
        }

        List<T> finisher() {
            T smallest = matches.first();
            if (smallest != null) {
                matches.remove(smallest);
            }

            matches.addAll(doesNot);
            return matches.stream().limit(size).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::accumulate, Acc::combine, Acc::finisher);
}
```

And usage would be:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = basket.getFruits()
            .stream()
            .collect(exceptCollector(Fruit::isPear, 20, Comparator.comparing(Fruit::getSize)));
```

Comment: I like your design. I'll give it a test!

Comment: I like the Collector solution! Would it help performance to also limit the treeSets' sizes to `size`, i.e. removing the largest elements if the sets exceed `size` in `accumulate` or `combine`? It keeps the number of comparisons smaller when adding further elements and helps keeping the number of held references in check in case your input gets large. Those gains might be offset by the size checks and remove calls, though.

Comment: @MalteHartwig I actually thought about that initially - but could not decide to do it or not, for large datasets you are certainly right, but for small and moderate - I can't tell. It would require lots of measurements... May be I'll try both and test that. thank you for the comment.

Comment: I like the idea of a stream of fruits going from a basket onto trees ;)

Comment: @Hulk :) that one great analogy!

Comment: @SilverQuettier did you try any solutions and their speed may be? can't find the time for it myself; but sounds really interesting what your riding would be.

Comment: @Eugene I definitely want to. :) I'll accept the solution my team settled on, but I'd like to offer back the community some insight on the pros and cons of these solutions. I can't find the time either, but I'll definitely update this with results next week at worst.

Comment: @Eugene I tried implementing your solution, it works well except when there's no pear. `matches.first()` on an empty `TreeSet` will throw a `NoSuchElementException`. I replaced it with a check to `matches.isEmpty()`. Expect metrics soon!

Comment: I have tested your solution amongst others. The results are above, feel free to challenge them if I made a mistake in the implementation. Thank you for your contribution! (@Eugene, maybe that can interest you)

Comment: @SilverQuettier I had a fast glance over the tests... I see one potentially big gap there - you do know that `@Benchmark` is supposed to return *something* right? Otherwise this is one broken test, besides you should use `@Fork` as well (not sure if you did)

Comment: @Eugene You are right, I totally did not return the results of the benchmarks. I will fix this and check if it changes the results, but it should be ok in this case. The "fork" value was set globally in the main class.

Answer (score 5):

For easier implementation, I attach an example for:

```
class Fruit {
    String name;
    Long size;
}
```

The following will work:

```
Comparator<Fruit> fruitComparator = (o1, o2) -> {

    if (o1.getName().equals("Peach") && o2.getName().equals("Peach")) {
        return o2.getSize().compareTo(o1.getSize()); //reverse order of Peaches
    }

    if (o1.getName().equals("Peach")) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (o2.getName().equals("Peach")) {
        return -1;
    }
    return o1.getSize().compareTo(o2.getSize());
};
```

And:

```
output = basket.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Fruit::getSize))
    .limit(21)
    .sorted(fruitComparator)
    .limit(20)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Fruit::getSize))
    .collect(fruitCollector);
```

My comparator will put the smallest Peach to the 21st position, will keep the order of other `Fruit`s natural, so in case there is not `Peach`, it will return 21st largest element. Then I sort the rest in the normal order.

This will work. It's a hack and at some circumstances might be a bad choice. I'd like to point out, that sorting 20 elements shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Ohgod. It's quite a hack indeed ;)
I'm a bit concerned about performance in the *real* case I'm working on, which doesn't involve fruits and might have much larger sets, but you could not know that from my question. I'll give your solution a try :)

Comment: I'd say that friuts appear much more often on [so] than in commercial projects. Although I have already worked in a project about vegetables and fruits :D

Comment: well what if there are less then 20 fruits?

Comment: I tried implementing your solution, it works well, but indeed @user140547 has a point, it fails if there is less input than the expected number of items. I'll publish benchmarks soon.

Comment: @SilverQuettier you can just make a check and in other case the solution is easier

Comment: I have tested your solution amongst others. The results are above, feel free to challenge them if I made a mistake in the implementation. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: @xenteros Thanks! It takes time, but I try :)

Answer (score 3):

The key action is to sort by type and size in such a way that the smallest pear 
goes first. Something like that:

```
// create a dummy pear; size value does not matter as comparing by ref
final Pear dummy = new Pear(-1);
basket
   // mix basket with the dummy pear
   .concat(basket, Stream.of(dummy))
      // sort by type so pears go first, then by size
      .sorted(Comparator
          .<Fruit>comparingInt(
              // arrange the dummy to always be the last 
              // among other pears but before other types 
              f -> (f == dummy ? 
                 0 : 
                 (Pear.class.equals(f.getClass()) ? -1 : 1))
          )
          .thenComparing(f -> f.size)
      )
      // skip the smallest pear
      .skip(1)
      // filter out the dummy
      .filter(f -> f != dummy)
      // sort again the rest by size
      .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(f -> f.size))
      // take 20 at max
      .limit(20);
```

Comment: This will skip another fruit if there is no pear.

Comment: Fixed that defect. Now a dummy pear is added to the basket. Later it is either skipped if no other pears or filtered out if there are other pears.

Comment: I like that concept of a dummy.

Comment: This is very nice! I fear this might not be "dummy"-proof however, and we'll have a catastrophe at the next internship, but bonus points for thinking outside the box!

Comment: +1 although I fear this solution will perform worse than the others for large baskets as you sort the whole stream twice

Comment: @Hulk Not quite true as some solutions do a triple sort,

Comment: Yes, but only the already limited stream - which may or may not better, depending on the relations of `basket.size()` to the limit (20 in the OP).

Comment: I have tested your solution amongst others. The results are above, feel free to challenge them if I made a mistake in the implementation. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 2):

Don’t try to filter upfront. Consider

```
List<Fruit> output = basket.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Fruit::getSize))
        .limit(21)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
int index = IntStream.range(0, output.size())
                     .filter(ix -> output.get(ix).isPear())
                     .findFirst().orElse(20);
if(index < output.size()) output.remove(index);
```

Just limit to `21` elements instead of `20` to be able to remove one. By using `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` you ensure to receive a mutable collection.

Then, there are three scenarios

1. The list contains a `Pear`. Since the list is sorted by the fruit sizes, the first `Pear` will also be the smallest `Pear`, which is the one that has to be removed. The subsequent `… .findFirst()` will evaluate to the index of the element.
2. The list does not contain a `Pear` but has a size of `21`. In this case, we have to remove the last element, i.e. at index `20`, to get the desired result size. This is provided by `.orElse(20)`, which will map an empty `OptionalInt` to `20`.
3. The list may not contain any `Pear` and be smaller than `21`, because the source list was already smaller. In this case, we don’t remove any elements, checked by prepending the `remove` operation with `if(index < output.size())`.

This entire post-processing can be considered irrelevant to the performance, as we already know beforehand, that it will be applied to a very small list, having at most `21` elements in this example. This is independent to the size of the source `basket` list.

Comment: An interesting solution! I'll give it a deeper look.

Comment: I have tested your solution amongst others. The results are above, feel free to challenge them if I made a mistake in the implementation. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

[Update], after reading the updated OP, I have a better understanding about the requirements: Here is the updated code by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
Optional<Integer> smallestPear = StreamEx.of(basket).filter(Fruit::isPear)
                                         .mapToInt(Fruit::getSize).min();

StreamEx.of(basket)
        .chain(s -> smallestPear.map(v -> s.remove(f -> f.isPear() && f.getSize() == v).orElse(s))
        .sortedBy(Fruit::getSize).limit(20).toList();
```

[update again]
The above solution is pretty similar with the solution provided by Misha. if you don't want to go through the stream twice, Here is another solution by limited Predicate if the pair of (fruit type, size) in basket are unique:

```
// Save this method in your toolkit.
public class Fn {
    public static <T> Predicate<T> limited(final Predicate<T> predicate, final int limit) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);    
        return new Predicate<T>() {
            private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(limit);
            @Override
            public boolean test(T t) {
                return predicate.test(t) && counter.decrementAndGet() >= 0;
            }
        };
    }
}

StreamEx.of(basket).sortedBy(Fruit::getSize)
        .remove(f -> Fn.limited(Fruit::isPear, 1))
        .limit(20).toList();
```

Comment: This won't work if the smallest pear is larger than another fruit. But this operation is available in Java 9.

Comment: You're right. Now I understand OP better by the updated samples. Answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Predicate` is the atomic operator of your operation. So the  simplest way is write your own `Predicate` to wrap the original `Predicate`. let's say the wrap named as `once` then your code can be simplify down to as below:

```
output = basket.stream().sorted(comparing(Fruit::getSize))
                        .filter(once(Fruit::isPear))
                        .limit(20).collect(fruitCollector);
```

---

```
static <T> Predicate<T> once(Predicate<T> predicate){
   boolean[] seen = {true};
   return it -> !seen[0] || (seen[0]=predicate.test(it));
}
```

If you want to support concurrent you can use an `AtomicInteger` instead, for example:

```
static <T> Predicate<T> once(Predicate<T> predicate){
   AtomicInteger seen = new AtomicInteger(0);

   return it -> {
     //if seen==0 then test predicate, otherwise increment only 
     IntBinaryOperator accumulator = (x,y)-> x==0 && predicate.test(it) ? x : x+y;
     return seen.accumulateAndGet(1, accumulator) != 1; 
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but solved by myself using a Map and ignore list. Here's the sample for your information. Hope can help.

```
@Test
public void testGetStckTraceElements() {
    StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

    // define a list for filter out
    List<String> ignoreClasses = Arrays.asList(
            Thread.class.getName(),
            this.getClass().getName()
    );

    // Map is using for check found before or not
    Map<String,Boolean> findFrist = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
    Arrays.asList(stElements).stream()
        .filter(s -> {
            Platform.print("check: {}", s.getClassName());
            if (Optional.ofNullable(findFrist.get(s.getClassName())).orElse(false)) {
                return true;
            }
            findFrist.put(s.getClassName(), true);
            for (String className:ignoreClasses) {
                if (s.getClassName().equals(className)) return false;
            }

            return true;

        })
        .forEach(s->{
            Platform.print("Result: {} {} {} {}", s.getClassName(), s.getMethodName(), s.getFileName(), s.getLineNumber());
    });

}
```

Comment: "Platform.print" is same as logger.info, if you get problem on this, please replaced by System.out.println(...) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might work (however groups into 2 baskets as you mentioned)

```
    Function<Fruit, Boolean> isPear = f -> f.getType().equals("Pear");
    Comparator<Fruit> fruitSize = Comparator.comparing(Fruit::getSize);
    Map<Boolean, List<Fruit>> pearsAndOthers = basket.sorted(fruitSize).limit(21).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(isPear));

    List<Fruit> pears = pearsAndOthers.get(true);
    List<Fruit> others = pearsAndOthers.get(false);

    Stream<Fruit> result;
    if (pears.size() == 0) {
        result = others.stream().limit(20);
    } else if (pears.size() == 1) {
        result = others.stream();
    } else {
        // You can probably merge in a nicer fashion since they should be sorted
        result = Stream.concat(pears.stream().skip(1), others.stream()).sorted(fruitSize);
    }
```